# How to set json array in a variable in php web service?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created a php function to get data from wordpress .  I have used function below to get data but this data is not coming in any variable :

```
function RecentPost()
 {

$my_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5,
   'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'));

foreach($my_posts as $post) {
      $data[] = 
        array(
           "id" => $post->ID,
          "title" => $post->post_title,
         "image" => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID,'thumbnail')),

        );
       }

echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

Output :

```
[
    {
        "id": 7101,
        "title": "BLACK FOREST CAKE ",
        "image": [
            "http://www.....jpg",
            150,
            150,
            true
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7100,
        "title": "MANGOCHIAN- IN GRAVY",
        "image": [
            "http://www.....jpg",
            150,
            150,
            true
        ]
    }
```

]

I want to put my json into some variable like this json :

```
{
    "next": {
        "$ref": "https://....."
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "empno": 7839,
            "ename": "KING",
            "job": "PRESIDENT",
            "hiredate": "1981-11-17T00:00:00Z",
            "sal": 5000,
            "deptno": 10
        }

    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer by myself :

i replaced  this line :echo json_encode($data);

with :

$items ['items']= $data;

echo json_encode($items );